# Supervise Any Non-Child Actor?

Tags: java, scala, akka, typesafe, typesafe-stack

This requirement may sound weird or may be I am not sure how to solve this problem, I am giving my best shot here to explain with following diagram

[image]

- I have an existing application (`Legacy Application`) which runs as single process.
- `Legacy Application` has very old dependencies on java version, slf4j, spring etc.
- In order to make it fault-tolerant and add some supervision to it I wrapped it inside an `Akka Actor` and start remotely in different JVM and Actor System.
- I start this legacy app from my new application as

> processor = context.actorOf(Props[Processor], "processor")

and my configuration looks like

```
deployment {
      /newApplication/processor/ {
        remote = "akka.tcp://ProcessingSystem@127.0.0.1:2552"
      }
```

But since `Processor` has all old dependencies, I get them in my new system as well :(

**What I am looking for?**
- Is there a way I can start the legacy application inside ActorSystem(and JVM) where it can be encapsulated but have supervisor in the new Application?

bottom-line: I want to have old dependencies not leak out, but since the other JVM can throw `OOM`, I would like to supervise from outside (new ActorSystem)

Comment: When you talk about dependencies, do you mean sbt library dependencies? Do you have the whole thing including the legacy application bundled together in one project?

Comment: the `legacyApplication` is bundled as one big jar with other dependencies inside

Answer (score 0):

About dependencies, just use Group Router, which sends messages via ActorSelection and don't require presence of target classes at senders side. But presence of Actors at this paths not managed by Group Router. More details at: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4-M2/scala/remoting.html

```
akka.actor.deployment {
  /parent/remoteGroup {
    router = round-robin-group
      routees.paths = [
        "akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.1:2552/user/workers/w1", 
        "akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.2:2552/user/workers/w1",
        "akka.tcp://app@10.0.0.3:2552/user/workers/w1"]
      }
}
```

About supervising: Just resolve ActorSelection (`resolveOne` method call) from paths (which used in the Group Router) and add `ActorRef` objects to `context.watch` of the actor in your new application then handle `Terminated` messages.